# How do I plot a function a=a(r, theta) in cylindrical coordinates in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

**a** is a 100x100 matrix containing the numerical solution of a differential equation.The function a(r, theta) does not have an explicit form in terms of r and theta.I have tried creating a mesh for r and theta using meshgrid and then converting the problem to the cartesian frame using pol2cart. But this does not work as **a** cannot be expressed in terms of r and theta.

```
[R, Theta]=meshgrid(r,theta);
[x,y,A]=pol2cart(Theta,r,a);
contourf(x,y,A,50,'linecolor','none');
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error may just be a matter of capitalization. 'r' -> 'R' produced a polar contour plot in my test implementation.

```
% Setting up the plotting ranges
r = 0:99;
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
[R, Theta]=meshgrid(r,theta);

a = R + Theta; % Your numerical solution goes here

[x,y,A]=pol2cart(Theta,R,a); % <- Your error is here?
contourf(x,y,A,50,'linecolor','none');
```

The arguments for the pol2cart function should have the same size.